# how to comsume authenticated soap functions in php please provide any working example

Tags: php, soap

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("AuthenticationHeader") is not a valid method for this service in D:\xampp\htdocs\soap\index_2.php:132 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\soap\index_2.php(132): SoapClient->__call('AuthenticationH...', Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\soap\index_2.php(132): SoapClient->AuthenticationHeader(Array) #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\soap\index_2.php on line 132

Comment: Some Code would be nice to see, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

There are must be only one request, you send three. You must create something like this:

1) Set header for authentication:

```
$auth = $auth = new SOAPAuth('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
$header = new SOAPHeader('urn:example.org/auth', 'AuthenticationHeader', $auth);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

2) Create create request with message text and contacts.

```
$result = $client->SendSMSToContacts(array("MessageText" => "some text", "contactIDs" => array(123456789, 123456789));

P.S. For the debugging create client with:

$client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => 1,));
and after sending request, look on request that was sended and resopnse on it:

var_dump("REQUEST=", $client->__getLastRequest());
var_dump("RESPONSE=", $client->__getLastResponse());
```

if you look at the error code you will see AuthenticationHeader is not a method! the error is very clear!

use [this](http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html)

or download soap ui. (google it!)

and you will see what method are available!

Comment: thanks for ur reply but in 2nd line what is 'urn:example.org/auth' you mean my wsdl url or some other else? and also its show 'Fatal error: Class 'SOAPAuth' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\soap\index_2.php on line 138'

Comment: use soap ui or any alternative for that check directory and example.org is your url with respect to your work if you want to integrate any site or somehow values getting or posting.